# Книга по веб-стандартам?

Tags: веб-программирование, книги, ui, документация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хочу прочитать или книгу или документацию по веб-стандартам, чтобы я мог аргументировать почему в форме справа кнопка сохранить, а слева отменить(это например) и тд. 
Что посоветуете?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону UI/UX

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что к тематике сайта не имеет отношения...

Comment: @Air, судя по количеству плюсов, тема как раз имеет отношение к тематике сайта.

Comment: ))))  Просто ты не единственный.. Кому надо что-то аргументировать...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что вам нужно, называется *User Interface Guidelines*. Однако для web-а нет никаких документально зафиксированных рекомендаций, поэтому можете поискать подобные документы для широко используемых настольных операционных систем, опыт взаимодействия с которыми является стандартом де-факто:

- [User Experience Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dn688964(v=vs.85).aspx) для Windows,
- [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) для OS X.